# Elasticsearch: Which analyser to use to search document through some special character

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to be able to search some documents on Elasticsearch using some special character and term. For example if I have the following document:

```
"HEY YOU! Thanks for reading this post!"
```

I want to be able to use query string like:

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "content",
        "query": "\"!\""
    }
 }
}
```

And having the previous document as the result. But I also want to be able to have the document by query:

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "content",
        "query": "hey AND you"
    }
 }
}
```

I'm currently using the Standard tokenizer but I can't query special characters, it return me no documents. 
Is there a tokenizer already define for this kind of task? I considered not analysing the field but I wouldn't have the lowercase part.

**EDIT**:

I created a custom analyser:

```
{
  "sw3": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "sw3",
        "creation_date": "1493907201172",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "e0_9cIFrQWqn-zqYeg0q5g",
        "version": {
          "created": "5030299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try:

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "content",
        "query": ";"
    }
 }
}
```

I don't get any result. So I tried to do:

```
{
 "query": {
    "match": {
        "content": ";"
    }
 }
}
```

but I still don't have any result. I try to see what exactly do the tokeniser:

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer
{
    "text": "Hey ; what's up"
}
```

And the result of the query is:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hey",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": ";",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "what's",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "up",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Why can't I retrieve any documents when the tokeniser seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom analyzer which does tokenization you need.

I'd love to provide an example - But This post in elastic forum gives a detailed answer.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-index-special-characters-and-search-those-special-characters-in-elasticsearch/42506/2

Comment: I update my questions with the result of your answer